# Inline style for .col elements

Tags: html, css

I would like to style the .col elements of a single page only. If I include in my css file:

```
.col {
        border: 1px solid #7851A9;
      }
```

Then the page will be styled, but the elements on another page will be styled as well, which I don't want that to happen.

I tried to style them inline but it doesn't work, I believe is my syntax that is wrong. But it is also wrong to style them inline.

How to make a specific css element so it will style only the specific elements and not all the .col ? I know my question is quite basic css, but I spend hours looking and trying different ways but no luck till now

```
<div ng-repeat="module in modules">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid #7851A;" ><h5 style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">{{module}}</h5></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-50" style="border:1px;"><h5 style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">Module Mark</h5></div>
                <div class="col col-50" style="border:1px solid #7851A;"><h5 style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">{{GenerateRandomMarks[$index]}}</h5></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
```

Comment: The hex value is wrong in the inline styles. Should be `#7851A9;`. You could also always add a unique class to, say, the `body` tag for this single page, and use the unique class to style this in CSS and keep it out of inline styles. `.uniqueClass .col { //whatever }`

Comment: True. Copy/Paste mistake.. Thanks for noting that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
.mycol {
        border: 1px solid #7851A9;
      }

<div ng-repeat="module in modules">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col mycol" ><h5 style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">{{module}}</h5></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-50" style="border:1px;"><h5 style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">Module Mark</h5></div>
                <div class="col col-50" style="border:1px solid #7851A;"><h5 style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">{{GenerateRandomMarks[$index]}}</h5>      </div>
            </div>
            <br>
           <br>
       </div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. jFatal was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can give that page a body class like "col-style" or whatever you prefer, then style anything within that class a certain way like:

```
.col-style .col { border: 1px solid #7851AA; }
```

Make sure you take out your other inline styles too and either put them in your global sheet or in the .col-style sheet above if you only want to style this page.

Answer (score 0):

How about on that specific page add another class next to col? Like

```
<div class="col specificStyle"></div>
```

and then apply

```
.specificStyle {
    color: red;
}
```

Those styles will override .col if you define them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class into the `<body` tag of that page, like

```
<body class="page5">
```

Then you can set up a CSS rule that uses a combined selector: The body class and your `.col` class, like

```
.page5 .col {
   border: 1px solid #7851A9;
 }
```

That way that class will only apply to the `.col`elements on that one page.